# Unable to call parseURDF on robot model

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm new to gazebo. Just installed whole software on Ubuntu14 with this one-line command

```
curl -ssL http://get.gazebosim.org | sh
```

Gazebo starts fine, I was able to create a model consisting of 1 cylinder and save it as:

```
balewski@ubuntu:~$ ll model_editor_models/Untitled/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 balewski balewski  237 Oct 31 21:30 model.config
-rw-rw-r-- 1 balewski balewski 2947 Oct 31 21:30 model.sdf
```

But when I try to load it next time with this command as see the error as below and  the cylinder is not showing up.

```
$ gazebo model_editor_models/Untitled/model.config 
Error [parser_urdf.cc:3423] Unable to call parseURDF on robot model
Error [parser.cc:309] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
```

Can you please advise me how to save/read-in my model or what software I am missing?

Thanks

Jan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14745/unable-to-call-parseurdf-on-robot-model/) by [balewski](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2893/balewski/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-10-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

(Even if your `model.config` setup is good)

This error can appear if there is an error in your urdf model, not a parsing error but another type, e.g. :

- It could be that you have multiple joints with the same name
- links with no parent and therefore not connected to the tree
- etc...

A quick way to check your urdf model is to do:

```
    check_urdf <(xacro model.urdf.xacro)
```

Credit for this last part : [ros answers post](https://answers.ros.org/question/9208/how-to-check-xacro-syntax-like-check_urdf/)

---

Originally posted by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3790/oscar-lima/) with karma: 26 on 2021-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1